# Is the union of two proper flows proper?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions, flows

Let $\varphi _t$ be a flow, aka. a one parameter group of homeomorphisms of the open subset $\Omega \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$, which we assume  to be continuous in the usual sense
that
$$
  (t, x)\in {\mathbb R}\times \Omega \mapsto \varphi _t(x)\in \Omega
  $$
is jointly continuous.

One says that $\varphi $ is  *proper*  when the map
$$
  \Psi :(t, x)\in {\mathbb R}\times \Omega \mapsto \big (\varphi _t(x), x\big )\in \Omega \times \Omega
  $$
is proper,  meaning that the inverse image under $\Psi $ of every compact set $K\subseteq \Omega \times \Omega $  is compact.

Properness may also be characterized by the fact that if $\{x_n\}_n$ is a sequence in $\Omega $, converging to some $x$ in $\Omega $,  and $\{t_n\}_n$ is a sequence in
${\mathbb R}$, such that $\varphi _{t_n}(x_n)$ converges to some $y$ in $\Omega $, then the $t_n$ are bounded.

---

For $i=1,2$, assume that $U_i$ is an open subset of $\Omega $,   invariant under $\varphi $,  and such that the restriction of $\varphi$ to $U_i$ is  a proper flow.

**Question**.
Is the flow restricted to $U:= U_1\cup U_2$ proper?

As far as I can see the proof should start as follows:  let $\{x_n\}_n\subseteq U$ converge to some $x\in U$, and such that
$$ y_n:=\varphi _{t_n}(x_n)$$ converges to $y\in U$.

If both $x$ and $y$ lie in $U_1$, or if both $x$ and $y$ lie in $U_2$, the conclusion is immediate.  So assume that $x\in U_1\setminus U_2$ and
$y\in U_2\setminus U_1$.  It follows that
$ x_n\in U_1,$  and $ y_n\in U_2,$
for all sufficiently large $n$, so we conclude
that $x_n$ and $y_n$ eventually lie in $U_1\cap U_2$ by invariance.

[image]
Therefore $x$ is in the boundary of $U_2$, and $y$ lies in the boundary of $U_1$.

Can't see where to go from here...  After struggling with it for a few hours I am beginning to feel like it might be false  :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the flow on $\Omega={\mathbb R}^2$ given by $$\varphi_t(x,y)=(e^tx, e^{-t}y).$$
Take $U_1$ equal to the open upper half-plane ($y>0$) and $U_2$ equal to the open right half-plane  ($x>0$). I leave it to you to verify that the flow is proper on both $U_1, U_2$ and is not proper on their union.

---

Edit.

1. The flow is proper on the open right half-plane because it is conjugate to the linear  flow
   $$
     \psi _t(x, y) = (x+t, y),
     $$
   on ${\mathbb R}^2$,  via the diffeomorphism
   $$
     (x, y)\in (0, +\infty )\times {\mathbb R}\ \mapsto  \ \big (\ln(x), xy\big )\in  {\mathbb R}^2.
     $$
   A similar reasoning implies properness of the flow on the open  upper half-plane.
2. The flow is not proper on the union $U=U_1\cup U_2$  because the sequence $\{v_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}\in U$, given by
   $$
     v_n=(e^{-n}, 1),
     $$
   converges to $(0,1)$, while for  $t_n=n$, we get
   $$
     \varphi_{t_n}(v_n) = (1, e^{-n})
     $$
   which converges to $(1,0)\in U$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer!   I have added a few  details to it but, since I do not have enough reputation,
someone must approve it first.